# How can I make a node link to another node

Tags: nodes, navigation

According to this site http://asblab.mie.utoronto.ca/news, you can see how 
Home>>News just below the menu. If I could add in this node http://asblab.mie.utoronto.ca/node/12525

such that Rise of the robots page would have

Home>>News>>Rise of the robots . How do I link them together?

Thank you guys, this forum has been helping me alot. If my question doesnt make sense, please inform me so I can try my best to edit and make the question better.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [drupal_set_breadcrumb()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_set_breadcrumb/7) in template file if you want to do it programmatic.

Or configure [Custom Breadcrumb](http://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) module.

Comment: hmmm,is there no other functionality within drupal features. I don't want to add that module because it was causing problems for my theme. Can I just make a menu link look active, but not taking care of where it goes , check this link http://asblab.mie.utoronto.ca/research , when you click on "assistive robotics" , you can see the menu tab"Research "  is still highlighted as active.

Comment: Do you want to add title of current page to breadcrumb?  What breadcrumb do you want to have on "assistive robotics" page?

Comment: I want the Research button menu, to look active.

Comment: I open http://asblab.mie.utoronto.ca/assistiveRobotics an see that Research button menu is active. So i don't see any problem!